# Getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 2

Tags: java, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception

I have this code

```
DefaultTableModel defaultTableModel = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

        int row = defaultTableModel.getRowCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            String id = (String) defaultTableModel.getValueAt(row, 0);
```

But I'm getting exception at line :

```
String id = (String) defaultTableModel.getValueAt(row, 0);
```

So even though `System.out.println(id);` able to return rows in `jTable`
I tried many other questions mentioned same problem but doesn't helpful.

Comment: `i < row + 1` - why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below change. I think it should work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) { // Changed row+1 to row
    String id = (String) defaultTableModel.getValueAt(i, 0); // Changed row to i
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` statement should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
```

Also as scary wombat says:

```
String id = (String) defaultTableModel.getValueAt(i, 0);
```

Comment: missing `getValueAt(row, 0);` - bug, should use `i`

Comment: You should leave it like you had it, but change the ending condition to `row - 1`. If you have for example 5 rows, and you start counting from 0, you want to count from 0 to 4 so you hit every row: 0, 1 ,2 ,3 and 4.

Comment: @gbandres You're almost there. Now replace the `row - 1` with `row`.

Comment: getValueAt(row, 0); that helped me. Thanks. I consider getValue(row) will return row . Yeah I had that row-1; from other answer.

Comment: You are right Robby, I was totally sure that they were using <= instead of <

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of time and efforts.

Comment: Using  <=  throws exception when there's only one row.

Comment: Yeah, using < is completly fine. If you had used <= then you would have needed to do `row - 1`. My bad :)